# Select2 search underlines matching text but does not filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am using jquery's select2 using input type ="hidden" and when I am searching in the select2, it only underlines the matching text but it doesnt hover at all. Do you have any idea about it? Here's my code.

```
_setSelectField: function(objField, strValue, arData) {
    // reset
    $(objField).select2('data', null);
    // Set up the brand_c field
    objField.select2({
        initSelection: function(element, callback) {
            var data = {
                id: element.data('value'),
                text: element.data('text')
            };
            callback(data);
        },
        minimumResultsForSearch: 1,
        placeholder: "Select Option",
        allowClear: true,
        val: $(this).data('value'),
        query: function(query) {
            // Initialise the results
            var objData = {
                results: []
            };
            // Do we have a matching set of divisions?
            if (arData != undefined) {
                // Loop through each brand
                $.each(arData, function(strKey, objDetail) {
                    // Add the result
                    objData.results.push({
                        id: strKey,
                        text: objDetail
                    });
                });
            } else {
                // Add warning message
                objData.results.push({
                    id: "",
                    text: "No Data to Load"
                });
            }
            // Set up the callback
            query.callback(objData);
        }
    });
}
```